# Using a for loop inside an expression

Tags: java, el

I have a requirement to concatenate a list of Strings using `Java EL`. Please note that this is not in a `JSP/Web context`, but in a standalone Java client (using `juel-2.2.4.jar`). 
The expression is of the form:

```
${for(int i=1; i<Employees.length; i++){Employee[i].Name + "--" }}
```

I already have a custom `ELResolver` which understands `Employee` objects.
The output I am expecting is a `String` with the names of all employees with a separator in between.

Is this even possible in a standalone `Java EL` application?

Comment: I think you will need to make create a method that returns the concatenated string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to make a helper function, afaik, there is no way java can handle this with an expression out of the box.

```
${Employee.joinEmployeesByName(Employees, "--")}
```

Code in the `Employee` class:

```
public static String joinEmployeesByName( Employee[] arr, String separator ) {
    //implement
}
```

Here's dynamic example using reflection:

```
public static String getFieldByName(Employee obj, String fieldName) {
    String ret = null;
    Class<?> c = obj.getClass();
    try {
        Field field = c.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        ret = field.get(obj).toString();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}

public static String joinEmployeesByField(Employee[] arr, String fieldName, String separator) {
    if(arr.length < 1) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    ret.append(getFieldByName(arr[0], fieldName));
    for( int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i ) {
        ret.append( separator );
        ret.append( getFieldByName( arr[i], fieldName) );
    }
    return ret.toString();
}
```

Usage would be:

```
${Employee.joinEmployeesByField(Employees, "Name", "--")}
${Employee.joinEmployeesByField(Employees, "Designation", "--")}
```

Comment: It needs to be more dynamic, because tomorrow I may want to change the expression to use the employee's designation field instead of employee name.

Comment: @Sandhya you could make the function take a property name by string, then use reflection to fetch properties of that name from the employee array

Comment: @Sandhya I have added a dynamic example

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. Your solution would work for me, except for one hitch: I am not allowed to make changes to the Employee class :) None the less, it is leading me towards implmenting this join method in a new helper class which I can create and call from my resolver. Will post an update once I am donr. I am not allowed to upvote you since I am still a SO newbie :(

Answer (score 0):

```
String allName="";
for(int i=1; i<Employees.length; i++){
allName+=Employee[i].Name + "--" 
}
```

Finally `allName` contains the concatenated name. As you started from i=1 be sure you are not missing the first employee's name;

What you asked in the comment you can't directly write something that will meet your requirement.Although you can do something like below;

```
public String getConcatenatedString(String property){
String allName="";
    for(int i=1; i<Employees.length; i++){
     if(property.equals("name")) 
     allName+=Employee[i].Name + "--";
     else if(property.equals("designation"))
      allName+=Employee[i].designation + "--"; 
    }
return allName;
}
```

You will call the method with name or property.You will get the concatenated property.

Comment: This is a simple for loop in compilable Java code. I am asking about the code being an expression that has to be executed dynamically at run-time. In other words, tomorrow I may change to Employee.designation instead of Employee.name and not have to change/recompile any Java code.